# How to convert yuv444 to yuyv422 using arm NEON?

Tags: arm, simd, neon, yuv

I want to convert color pattern from `yuv444` to `yuyv422`.
Currently, I am using `c` to convert which is slower.
Does anyone know how to convert color pattern using `arm NEON` ?
Below is my code using `c`:

```
{

    unsigned int i, j;
    unsigned int y1, y2, cb, cr, i_rows;
    const unsigned char *p;

    p = src;
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        i_rows = i*2*width;
        for (j = 0; j < 2*width; j += 4) {
            y1 = p[0];
            cb = (p[1] + p[4] + 1) >> 1;
            y2 = p[3];
            cr = (p[2] + p[5] + 1) >> 1;
            *(dst + i_rows + j  ) = y1;
            *(dst + i_rows + j+1) = cb;
            *(dst + i_rows + j+2) = y2;
            *(dst + i_rows + j+3) = cr;
            p += 6;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to try and implement this yourself and then come back with specific questions if you get stuck at any point.

Comment: That looks like it _should_ be fairly straightforward to vectorise (no nasty dependencies between elements), although the 6-byte length means you'll probably want to process several pixels at once to maintain load/store alignment, entailing a bit of non-vectorised cleanup at the end(s). The [NEON programmer's guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0018a/index.html) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I'd have a look to see whether OpenCV has an optimised implementation of this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
vld3.8      {d16, d18, d20}, [pSrc]!
vld3.8      {d17, d19, d21}, [pSrc]!

vtrn.8      q9, q10

vrhadd.u8   q9, q10, q9

vst2.8      {q8, q9}, [pDst]!
```

Above is what I'd put in the main loop. The rest is up to you.